# Sorting a referenced list in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Lets say I have some simple classes for a twitter-like app:

- User
- Post

A user hasMany posts, and a post belongsTo a user.

Now, I'm trying to get a list of posts for a specific user in **order of date**.

I know I can get a list of all posts (for all users) by:

```
def posts = Post.list([sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'asc', max:10])
```

But to limit it to my particular user I need to reference the user I want and I am supposing that I need to switch from a static call to something like this where I reference the user first:

```
def user = User.findByUserId(userId)
def posts = user.posts
```

So now that will return a list of all the posts for that user, but how do organise that list so that they are ordered such as [sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'asc', max:10] to retrieve the first 10 in the correct order?

Or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update, based on conversation:*

```
def user = User.findByUserId('steve')
def posts = Post.findAllByUser(user, [sort: 'dateCreated', order:'asc', max: 10])
```

Comment: That's good, but is there anyway I can limit the DB retrieval to a batch of 10? Or do I have to retrieve all and then manipulate in memory?

Comment: I _think_ you should be able to use `GORM` to retrieve posts using something similar to Post.findByUser(user, [sort: 'dateCreated', order:'asc', max: 10]). See http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html

Comment: Sweeeeet!

    def user = User.findByUserId('steve')
    def posts = Post.findAllByUser(user, [sort: 'dateCreated', order:'asc', max: 10])

Thanks!

Comment: Accepted for Robert's comment afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

If you always want to retrieve the posts this way you can add a mapping block to the User class.  Something like this:

```
static mapping = {
    posts sort:'dateCreated', batchSize:10
}
```

Comment: Good Call Dave :-)  
http://grails.org/doc/1.1.1/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.3%20Default%20Sort%20Order
 
Keep in mind the order doesn't work on the mapping dsl yet:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3778